# Linking libraries using CMake and PkgConfig

Tags: cmake, glfw, pkg-config

I am trying to link a static library (GLFW) to my own library that I am building. I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt file in order to do this:

```
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${GLFW_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
```

When linking my library, I get the following error: `ld: library not found for -lglfw3`

Yet, running `pkg-config --libs glfw3` in the console gives:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3
```

So I know that the GLFW library is installed. Why isn't the library being found when I try linking using CMake?

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by adding -lglfw manually to my target_link_libraries list, but i would like to know why pkg_search_module doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the library name but not the the linker search path. Try:

```
link_directories(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using the argument `-lglfw3`, and after much trial and error I found I needed to use `-lglfw.3`